# Cloning MongoDB for running Tests

Tags: mongodb, spring-mongodb

I have a set of @Tests running in my Spring Boot application that I want to run against a clone of my test Mongo(4.2) database (but against the same Mongo server - copyDatabase is not available).

My question is what is the easiest way to make an entire clone of a database and change its name (but keep it in the same actual mongo instance)?  Basically, I'm looking for the equivalent of "cp myOrigMongoDB MyTestMongoDB" within the mongo cluster.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/) and [mongorestore](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongorestore/#bin.mongorestore) ?

Comment: I haven't found the right syntax that acts as a local "copy and rename"